# Tail - like tool for log files

Tags: command-line, gui, log, text-editor, tail

I want a tool that offers `tail`-like functionality for large files. (which are in a remote server and mounted on my system, for what that matters).

I am aware of [glogg](http://glogg.bonnefon.org/) but I am having issues with auto reload on Ubuntu 16.04.01 as I describe [here](https://github.com/nickbnf/glogg/issues/135).

Incorporation of custom coloring schemes is also needed.

I would like to avoid terminal based solutions such as `multiline` and [lnav](http://lnav.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use less to tail a file. Just type 'tail ' and press shift+f to start tailing it. Ctrl+c to break out of tail while remaining in file. You can type forward slash to do a search forwards in the file, and ? to search backwards in file. Both searches will highlight search terms.